# add modal confirm or delete

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have created a simple javascript alert

```
if (confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this item?')) {
        swoosh(id, path+'swoosh_config/swoosh_delete_jobtitle', 'jobtitledv')
    }
```

which i change it into a modal.

```
$('#delete').modal('show');
```

and here is my new alert

```
<div class="modal fade" id="delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-haspopup="true" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="alert alert-info fade in" id="alert">
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                     <h4>Heads Up!</h4>
                     <p>What you are doing will delete a data!</p>
                </div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

how will i add a confirmation button that will lead me to that "swoosh" plus it's link.?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation maybe that helps you

Answer (score 0):

see **[jquery dialog confirmation box](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation)**

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal confirmation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:140,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Delete all items": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
</div>

<p>Sed vel diam id libero <a href="http://example.com">rutrum convallis</a>. Donec aliquet leo vel magna. Phasellus rhoncus faucibus ante. Etiam bibendum, enim faucibus aliquet rhoncus, arcu felis ultricies neque, sit amet auctor elit eros a lectus.</p>


</body>
</html>
```